# Using array and loop in firebase setValue

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add data in firebase child using hashMap with array and for loop. But the value is overwriten instead of creating new child with new index. Here is code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    medicineName[i] = medName[i].getText().toString();
    HashMap<String, String> anxietyData = new HashMap<>();
    anxietyData.put("medicine_date", medDate);
    anxietyData.put("medicine_name" + i, medicineName[i]);
    mref.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child("data").child("medicine_detail").setValue(anxietyData);
}
```

This is database value:

[image]

I hope the code is clear. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: The problem is at the "Medicine detail" node. It will always overwrite because you code tells it to. What you might have to do is add an extra child after "Medicine Detail". Maybe add a .push() before the setValue() to add an automated generated key

Comment: but i want to make a new medicine_name[i] node in the medicine detail. How that will be implemented?

Comment: Please see the answer below. I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
medicineName[i] = medName[i].getText().toString();
HashMap<String, String> anxietyData = new HashMap<>();
anxietyData.put("medicine_date", medDate);
anxietyData.put("medicine_name" + i, medicineName[i]);
mref.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .child("data").child("medicine_detail").child("medicine" + i).setValue(anxietyData);
}
```

This will add the extra child. So the node will be "Medicine Detail" - "Medicine1" - Hashmap details. This will prevent it from being overwritten

Comment: Is it possible to provide index in hashmap? so that each index value is stored only in medcine_detail node?

Comment: Medicine detail node requires one more child before setting the value, otherwise Firebase will overwrite the node the whole time.